# Concurrent Collection, reporting custom progress data to UI when parallel tasking

Tags: user-interface, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, c#-5.0, parallel.foreach

I have a concurrent collection that contains 100K items.  The processing of each item in the collection can take as little as 100ms or as long as 10 seconds. I want to speed things up by parallelizing the processing, and have a 100 minions doing the work simultaneously. I also have to report some specific data to the UI as this processing occurs, not simply a percentage complete.

I want the parallelized sub-tasks to nibble away at the concurrent collection like a school of minnows attacking a piece of bread tossed into a pond.  How do I expose the concurrent collection to the parallelized tasks?  Can I have a normal loop and simply launch an async task inside the loop and pass it an IProgress? Do I even need the concurrent collection for this?

It has been recommended to me that I use Parallel.ForEach but I don't see how each sub-process established by the degrees of parallelism could report a custom object back to the UI with *each* item it processes, not only after it has finished processing its share of the 100K items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework already provides the [IProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298.aspx) inteface for this purpose, and an implementation in [Progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx). To report progress, call [IProgress.Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193864.aspx) with a progressvalue. The value T can be any type, not just a number.

Each IProgress implementation can work in its own way. Progress raises an event and calls a callback you pass to it when you create it.

Additionally, Progress.Report executes asynchronously. Under the covers, it uses [SychronizationContext.Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) to execute its callback and all event handlers on the thread that created the Progress instance.

Assuming you create a progress value class like this:

```
class ProgressValue
{
    public long Step{get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

You could write something like this:

```
IProgress<ProgressValue> myProgress=new Progress<ProgressValue>(p=>
{
    myProgressBar.Value=p.Step;
});

IList<int> myVeryLargeList=...;
Parallel.ForEach(myVeryLargeList,item,state,step=>
{
    //Do some heavy work
    myProgress.Report(new ProgressValue
    {
         Step=step,
         Message=String.Format("Processed step {0}",step);
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Oops! Progress implements IProgress explicitly. You have to cast it to IProgress , as @Tim noticed.

Fixed the code to explicitly declare myProgress as an IProgress.

Comment: Can the "heavy work" be a synchronous method? Can an async method be awaited inside Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: Parallel.Foreach is made to execute synchronous jobs in parallel, over a large amount of data.  You *can* await inside a Parallel.ForEach by adding the `async` keyword before the lambda declaration but you should probably rethink it, as Parallel.Foreach would end up just creating and waiting on tasks. A better solution would be to use a pipeline of parallel steps to process the data generated from the previous step. TPL Dataflow is one implementation  for this

Comment: I'm getting an error that myProgress `does not contain a definition for 'Report'` when I invoke `myProgress.Report(..`

Comment: Figured it out; have to cast to IProgress:  `(myProgress as IProgress<myCustomProgressType>).Report()`

Comment: This approach, where a synchronous method is invoked within the parallelized loop, causes the UI to become unresponsive. The form cannot be dragged to another place on the screen while the loop is processing.

Comment: Progress.Report runs asynchronously, that's the entire point. Under the covers it uses If your UI blocks there must be another issue.